# How use SVG.js with Webpack?

Tags: svg, webpack

**yarn add @svgdotjs/svg.js**
how to use this library now?
import * as SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'

```js
var draw = SVG('drawing').size(300, 300)
var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
```

not work

```js
console.log('SVG is ', SVG)
```

[image: console.log result]

Answer (score 0):

```
import * as _SVG from '@svgdotjs/svg.js'  
const canvas = _SVG.SVG().addTo('#drawing').size(300, 300)
var rect = canvas.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: '#f06' })
```

with documentation problem
not sure what is the best solution